# How can one use mo with desu

Tags: grammar, particle-も

Forgive me for this beginner question, but is there a way to use も with です? I learned that も means 'also', and either replaces or is added to the particle e.g.

私は寿司も食べました。
"I also ate sushi (among other things)."

私は図書館にも行きました。
"I also went to the library (among other places)."

However, です doesn't take a particle, does it? Can I say "私は学生もです" to mean "I am also a student (as well as being other things)", or is there a different way to say it?

Sidenote: It's only after writing this question that I realize how the English "also" is ambiguous between whether it refers to subject or object...

Comment: @istrasci Thanks for the link! I didn't realize desu was a contraction of de arimasu. It helps explain Angelos's answer too.

Answer (score 1):

In this case you would use でもあります, as in for example 「店員だけでなく、学生でもあります。」